# How to pass data from the listview tapped event to a telerik dataform in another page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, telerik

I need to pass data from a ListView to a TodoDetail page where I have a Telerik DataForm, but I don't know how to make it work. If I use normal Xamarin Forms controls it works fine, but need it to work with the Telerik DataForm control.

Here is my code:

​Todo.xaml
list item tapped handler

```
private async void ToDoTaskTap(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var user = ToDoTask.SelectedItem as tblEmpTask;
    if (user != null)
    {
        var mainViewModel = BindingContext as MainViewModel;
        if (mainViewModel != null)
        {
            mainViewModel.Selected = user;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ToDoDetail(mainViewModel));    ​
        }
    }
}
```

tblEmpTask.cs

```
public  class tblEmpTask
{
    public string strTaskName { get; set; }
}
```

TodoDetail.xaml

```
<telerikInput:RadDataForm x:Name="dataForm">
    <telerikInput:RadDataForm.Source>
        <local1:MainViewModel />
    </telerikInput:RadDataForm.Source>
</telerikInput:RadDataForm>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ​public tblEmpTask Selected
    {
        get { return _Selected; }
        set
        {
            _Selected = value;
            OnPropertChanged();
        }
    }
        ​
    [DisplayOptions(Header = "Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.Selected.strTaskName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.Selected.strTaskName)
            {
                this.Selected.strTaskName = value;
                OnPropertChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a binding between the `SelectedItem` and the `ListView`

Here's an example:

ViewModel:

```
public List<object> ItemsSource { get; set; }

public object SelectedItem {
    set { SelectedItemChanged(value); }
}

async void SelectedItemChanged(object value) {
    await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutPage(SelectedItem));
}
```

Page:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding .}"></Label>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: For auto implement property changed interface i recommend use Fody.PropertyChanged

Comment: i think u didnt get my question i have listview and when i tap listview i pass all data to new page which is tododetail page, if i use xamarin control its working fine but i want to use telerik form data in tododetail page and i  am stuck here

Comment: Use  `<telerikInput:RadDataForm.GestureRecognizers><TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CustomCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer></telerikInput:RadDataForm.GestureRecognizers>
`

Comment: what will be custom command? i mean what will be code in this command?

Comment: Thiss property from ViewModel `public ICommand CustomCommand=> _customCommand?? new Command(() => { Console.WriteLine("CustomLogic"); });`

Comment: i didnt get u i need answer related to my question can u check my question and check my viewmodel? can you give me related code from my view model